# bar.with{ ... this.@foo = ... }: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MyClass.setFoo() is applicable for argument types

Tags: groovy

(using `Groovy 2.4.11`)
The following pseudo-modified code:

```
enum EnumClass { a, b }

class Some {

   Foo foo

   Some() {
     EnumClass.with{ this.@foo = new Foo( a ) }
   }

   Some  setFoo( String _foo ) {  ... }
}
```

is called like `new Some()` and brings up the following runtime exception:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: MyClass.setFoo() is applicable for argument types: (Foo) values: [Foo$12345] ...`

It **looks as if the compiler thinks** there would be some **`this.foo = ...` instead of `this.@foo = ...`**. :-(
(This should not happen as I understand it and seems to be some bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: writing it like this (outside the `with`-closure) works ...

```
enum EnumClass { a, b }

class Some {

   Foo foo

   Some() {
     //EnumClass.with{ this.@foo = new Foo( a ) }  // throws exception
     this.@foo = new Foo( EnumClass.a )            // works
   }

   Some  setFoo( String _foo ) {  ... }
}
```